# jqGrid wont Display, Only the count show

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm still starting to learn jquery and JavaScripts. I'm trying to display items using a jqGrid. I can't understand it totally. I hope you can help me and hopefully baby steps on the explanation on why it didn't work. Here is my code. Im also using .NetCore 1.0. My objective is to display the items on a table. It only add blank rows and the row count. But no item details.

[image: Click here for image of the form]

**jqGrid**

```
//Load Table
function LoadTable(param) {
  //Loading(true);
  $("#tblItem").jqGrid("GridUnload");
  $("#tblItem").jqGrid("GridDestroy");
  $("#tblItem")
    .jqGrid({
      url: window.getItemListURL,
      postData: param,
      autowidth: true,
      datatype: "json",
      mtype: "POST",
      colNames: [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "PLU",
        "Category",
        "Display Name",
        "Description",
        "Unit Cost",
        "UOM",
        "Mark-Up",
        "Good For",
        "Selling Price",
        "Is Taxable",
      ],
      colModel: [
        { name: "edit", index: "edit", width: 20, align: "center", sortable: false },
        { name: "delete", index: "delete", width: 20, align: "center", sortable: false },
        {
          key: true,
          hidden: true,
          name: "Id",
          index: "Id",
          editable: false,
          edittype: "checkbox",
          editoptions: { value: { false: "No", true: "Yes" } },
        },
        { key: false, name: "PLU", index: "1", width: 150, editable: true, align: "left", sortable: true },
        { key: false, name: "CategoryID", index: "2", editable: false, width: 150, align: "left", sortable: true },
        { key: false, name: "DisplayName", index: "3", width: 150, editable: false, align: "left", sortable: true },
        { key: false, name: "Description", index: "4", width: 150, editable: false, align: "left", sortable: true },
        { key: false, name: "UnitCost", index: "16", width: 150, editable: false, align: "left", sortable: true },
        { key: false, name: "UOM", index: "15", editable: false, align: "left", sortable: true },
        { key: false, name: "MarkUp", index: "5", editable: false, align: "left", sortable: true },
        { key: false, name: "GoodFor", index: "6", editable: false, width: 150, align: "left", sortable: true },
        { key: false, name: "SellingPrice", index: "7", editable: false, align: "left", sortable: true },
        { key: false, name: "IsTaxable", index: "8", editable: false, align: "left", sortable: true },
      ],
      pager: $("#divPager"),
      rowNum: 10,
      rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
      loadonce: false,
      viewrecords: true,
      jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
      },
      emptyrecords: "No records to display",
      rowNumbers: true,
      sortorder: "desc",
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      sortable: true,
      onPaging: function(pgButton) {},
      loadComplete: function() {},
      loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var msg = "";
        if (xhr.responseJSON !== undefined) {
          if (xhr.responseJSON.IsListResult) {
            for (var i = 0; i < xhr.responseJSON.Result.length; i++) {
              msg += xhr.responseJSON.Result[i] + "<br />";
            }
          } else {
            msg += xhr.responseJSON.Result;
          }
        } else {
          msg = $(xhr.responseText)
            .filter("title")
            .text();
        }
        alert(msg);

        //Loading(false);
      },
    })
    .navGrid("#divPager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
}
```

**CSHTML Code**

```
    <head>
    <title>Maintenance</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="Create" class="col-md-12 form-group text-center mt-3">
                <a asp-action="CreateItem">Create Item</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group text-center mt-3">
                <a asp-action="ViewItem">View Item</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @* --- SEARCH AREA --- *@
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" class="col-md-2" name="search" placeholder="Search.." />
        <button id="btnSearch">S</button>
        <button id="btnRefresh">R</button>
        <button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
        <button id="btnDeleteAll">X</button>
    </div>

    @* ----- TABLE ----- *@
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="mt-12 mb-5">
            <table id="tblItem" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
            <div id="divPager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ViewAllItem()
{
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ENTITIES.ENT_Items> ent_Items;
    ViewModels.ViewModel_ItemMaintenance vm_ItemMaintenance = new ViewModels.ViewModel_ItemMaintenance();
    using (Models.H2POSContext db = new Models.H2POSContext(_options))
    {
        ent_Items = db.t_Items.ToList();

    }

    var jsonData = new
    {
        rows = ent_Items.ToArray(),
        page = 1,
        total = 1,
        records = 1,
        sort = ""
    };
    return Json(jsonData);
}
```

**Update**
I just found out that the jqgrid is not receiving any data. From the controller there was a data but when it was transferred to the jqgrid its blank. Does anybody know on how do i start to find the problem?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? - Guriddo jqGrid, free jqGrid or jqGrid <= ver 4.7?

Comment: @TonyTomov.. sorry for the late reply.. it says here its..@license jqGrid  4.6.0 - jQuery Grid .. .. is jqGrid differs of its version?..

Comment: Could you please post the data (or part of it) returned from the server. You can get it using the debug console.